# Is there a way to reset the Emacs keymap?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to reset the keymap so that I can manually enable features with an appropriate keybinding. I'm trying to do a customized Emacs build and would like full control over the keybindings and features enabled.

Edit: Thanks for the answers, this answered what I was looking for perfectly. I was trying to Google it and I couldn't find much but now I'm starting to understand Emacs more.

Basically I'm trying to learn it and customize the keybindings to my preferences. Though I have had trouble overriding some keybindings but the suggestions of disabling major mode was what I was looking for.

Comment: You already have full control over the keybindings in emacs, typically through using elisp in your .emacs file - no need to do a custom build. If you need to do something that can't be done with normal customization procedures (is there anything that can't be done this way?), you need to give us more details about your objectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Emacs will give you full control, there are a couple different ways to accomplish what it sounds like you're trying to do.  To be successful though, I recommend you read and understand the [Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html#Keymaps) section of the manual.  If your customized Emacs build uses any major or minor modes, you'll have to do special work to disable/override any keymaps they set.

Of particular interest are the sections [Creating Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Keymaps.html#Creating-Keymaps), [Active Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html#Active-Keymaps), [Controlling Active Maps](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html#Controlling-Active-Maps), and ... pretty much the whole chapter.

I recommend starting with creating a basic keymap and overriding the global keymap with yours.  That'd be a good start.  Probably the easiest way would be to do something like:

```
(setq global-map (make-keymap))
(global-set-key ...)
```

Though, you're also going to have to disable the major modes from setting up their keys, the easiest way would be to disable automatic choosing of major modes by doing this:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist nil)
```

Read the section on [How Emacs Chooses a Major Mode](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html#Auto-Major-Mode).

The question needs more detail to enable writing a more detailed answer...

Comment: This article is another good reference: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/

Answer (score 1):

You may bundle the features into a minor-mode with its own keymap.  When the minor-mode is enabled, its keymap will be consulted before the global-map, overriding the latter in effect.  When disabled, the default key bindings in the global-map will be visible again.